# RegEx for string starts with numbers and followed by letters

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

I want Regular expression for such inputs.

```
1
1a
1b
1c
1d
2
2a
2b
2c
```

But if i write following inputs then it should not allow.

```
a
b
c
```

The string must start with 1 or 2 (only once and mandatory) and then followed by any character between a to z(only once)

So total string length is 2 only

the first letter will be always 1 or 2 (first letter is mandatory)
second letter will be a to z (not mandatory)

I tried this `[1-2]?[a-zA-Z]?` but it allow me to enter string starts with any character..

I want this RegEx for C#.Net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to anchor the regular expression - you need to specify that they need to be at the start of the string.

You also need to specify that 1 or 2 *has* to be there. There are several ways to do so, I chose alternation `(1|2)`, thought the character class is another option (`[12]`).

You do that by starting the regex with `^`:

```
^(1|2)[a-zA-Z]?
```

So, the above will match

Comment: Also remove the ? since from his description it's not an optional match. (And maybe use $ at the end, although that's not entirely clear from his post)

Comment: @Dirk - Thanks - I looked at the first part and didn't note the other requirement.

Comment: The OP mentioned that he would like just the number to match. 1 should match if you remove the optional flag it wouldn't.

Comment: @Carlos13 - I don't follow.

Answer (score 0):

this will do it    `^(1|2)[a-zA-Z]?$`